# switch statement in php

Tags: php, algorithm

I found this snippet calculating Chinese zodiac based on the year.

```
<?php
 $year = 2016;
 switch (($year-4 ) % 12) {
    case 0 : $zodiac = 'Rat' ;  break ;
    case 1 : $zodiac = 'Ox' ;  break ;
    case 2 : $zodiac = 'Tiger' ;  break ;
    case 3 : $zodiac = 'Rabbit' ;  break ;
    case 4 : $zodiac = 'Dragon' ;  break ;
    case 5 : $zodiac = 'Snake' ;  break ;
    case 6 : $zodiac = 'Horse' ;  break ;
    case 7 : $zodiac = 'Goat' ;  break ;
    case 8 : $zodiac = 'Monkey' ;  break ;
    case 9 : $zodiac = 'Rooster' ;  break ;
    case 10 : $zodiac = 'DOG' ;  break ;
    case 11 : $zodiac = 'Pig' ;  break ;     
 }
echo "{$year} is the year of the {$zodiac}.";
 ?>
```

I was wondering why they first deduct `4` before doing a switch on the remainder?

Comment: its up to you what logic you want pass in it. exactly what you want to do ?

Comment: It is unclear what you want and what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because the [Chinese Zodiac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_zodiac)'s 12-year cycle does not synchronize with the [Gregorian Calender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar) (the one we use).

The Chinese Zodiac's 12-year cycle typically begins with "Rat" (as seen in your code). However, the Gregorian Calender's year "0 AD" isn't "Rat". The closest year of the rat to the turn of the Era is actually in the year 4 AD.

Thus, to correctly align the calendar with the zodiac, and make it simpler to read, the programmer decided to simply subtract 4 from the year first, rather than changing all the numbers (Making rabbit=0, dragon=1, etc)